# Compiling a basic OpenCV program on Mac OS X 10.7

Tags: c, macos, opencv

I installed opencv from Macports and it is in 
/opt/local/include

I tried to compile basic OPENCV code from Terminal by giving the following commands, but it doesn't getting compiled:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example -I /usr/local/include/opencv/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_legacy
g++ example.cpp -o example -I /opt/local/include/opencv/ -L /opt/local/lib/ -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_legacy
```

**Can anyone tell me the right Terminal command to compile given below opencv program for Mac OS X 10,7?**

I was trying to compile the simple example given on this link:
http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/

**Edit:**

Here is the code I am trying to compile:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// hello-world.cpp
//
// This is a simple, introductory OpenCV program. The program reads an
// image from a file, inverts it, and displays the result. 
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  IplImage* img = 0; 
  int height,width,step,channels;
  uchar *data;
  int i,j,k;

  if(argc<2){
    printf("Usage: main <image-file-name>\n\7");
    exit(0);
  }

  // load an image  
  img=cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
  if(!img){
    printf("Could not load image file: %s\n",argv[1]);
    exit(0);
  }

  // get the image data
  height    = img->height;
  width     = img->width;
  step      = img->widthStep;
  channels  = img->nChannels;
  data      = (uchar *)img->imageData;
  printf("Processing a %dx%d image with %d channels\n",height,width,channels); 

  // create a window
  cvNamedWindow("mainWin", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE); 
  cvMoveWindow("mainWin", 100, 100);

  // invert the image
  for(i=0;i<height;i++) for(j=0;j<width;j++) for(k=0;k<channels;k++)
    data[i*step+j*channels+k]=255-data[i*step+j*channels+k];

  // show the image
  cvShowImage("mainWin", img );

  // wait for a key
  cvWaitKey(0);

  // release the image
  cvReleaseImage(&img );
  return 0;
}
```

**And here is the output:**

```
singhg@~/Programming/opencvTest $ g++ example.c -o example 'pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv'
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv: No such file or directory
example.c:14:16: error: cv.h: No such file or directory
example.c:15:21: error: highgui.h: No such file or directory
example.c: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
example.c:21: error: ‘IplImage’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:21: error: ‘img’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:23: error: ‘uchar’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:23: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:32: error: ‘cvLoadImage’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
example.c:43: error: expected `;' before ‘img’
example.c:47: error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:47: error: ‘cvNamedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:48: error: ‘cvMoveWindow’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:55: error: ‘cvShowImage’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:58: error: ‘cvWaitKey’ was not declared in this scope
example.c:61: error: ‘cvReleaseImage’ was not declared in this scope
```

Edit[6Dec]:

```
singhg@~/Programming/opencvTest $ g++ example.cpp -o example `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'opencv' found
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: example.cpp: No such file or directory
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2: no input files
singhg@~/Programming/opencvTest $
```

---

in my `/opt/local/lib` I have:

```
singhg@/opt/local/lib $ ls *cv*
libopencv_calib3d.2.3.1.dylib       libopencv_highgui.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.2.3.dylib     libopencv_imgproc.2.3.1.dylib
libopencv_calib3d.dylib         libopencv_imgproc.2.3.dylib
libopencv_contrib.2.3.1.dylib       libopencv_imgproc.dylib
libopencv_contrib.2.3.dylib     libopencv_legacy.2.3.1.dylib
libopencv_contrib.dylib         libopencv_legacy.2.3.dylib
libopencv_core.2.3.1.dylib      libopencv_legacy.dylib
libopencv_core.2.3.dylib        libopencv_ml.2.3.1.dylib
libopencv_core.dylib            libopencv_ml.2.3.dylib
libopencv_features2d.2.3.1.dylib    libopencv_ml.dylib
libopencv_features2d.2.3.dylib      libopencv_objdetect.2.3.1.dylib
libopencv_features2d.dylib      libopencv_objdetect.2.3.dylib
libopencv_flann.2.3.1.dylib     libopencv_objdetect.dylib
libopencv_flann.2.3.dylib       libopencv_ts.2.3.1.dylib
libopencv_flann.dylib           libopencv_ts.2.3.dylib
libopencv_gpu.2.3.1.dylib       libopencv_ts.dylib
libopencv_gpu.2.3.dylib         libopencv_video.2.3.1.dylib
libopencv_gpu.dylib         libopencv_video.2.3.dylib
libopencv_highgui.2.3.1.dylib       libopencv_video.dylib
libopencv_highgui.2.3.dylib
singhg@/opt/local/lib $
```

Now I used this command:

```
   singhg@~/Programming/opencvTest $ g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world -I /opt/local/include/opencv/ -L /opt/local/lib  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
In file included from hello-world.cpp:12:
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:63:33: error: opencv2/core/core_c.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:64:33: error: opencv2/core/core.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:65:39: error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:66:39: error: opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:67:38: error: opencv2/video/tracking.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:68:45: error: opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:69:35: error: opencv2/flann/flann.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:70:39: error: opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:71:43: error: opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:72:37: error: opencv2/legacy/compat.hpp: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/cv.h:79:37: error: opencv2/core/internal.hpp: No such file or directory
In file included from hello-world.cpp:13:
/opt/local/include/opencv/highgui.h:47:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h: No such file or directory
/opt/local/include/opencv/highgui.h:48:39: error: opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp: No such file or directory
hello-world.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
hello-world.cpp:18: error: ‘IplImage’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:18: error: ‘img’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:20: error: ‘uchar’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:20: error: ‘data’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:29: error: ‘cvLoadImage’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:40: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
hello-world.cpp:40: error: expected `;' before ‘img’
hello-world.cpp:44: error: ‘CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:44: error: ‘cvNamedWindow’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:45: error: ‘cvMoveWindow’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:52: error: ‘cvShowImage’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:55: error: ‘cvWaitKey’ was not declared in this scope
hello-world.cpp:58: error: ‘cvReleaseImage’ was not declared in this scope
singhg@~/Programming/opencvTest $
```

Comment: What is the error output? Post that as part of you question.

Comment: Yes I just added the error output.

Comment: Please see the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Or use **pkg-config** to assist you filling in the paths and libraries:

```
g++ example.cpp -o example `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Comment: It still giving me the same errors as mentioned in my post. (I edited it this afternoon)

Comment: You used `'` to delimit the **pkg-config** stuff, and it's suposed to be: `\``

Comment: oh okay now I am getting these errors mentioned in my post above

Comment: This post can be stopped. I resolved the problem (as mentioned above) and now opencv works fine on Mac OS X 10.7. Thanks a lot everyone!

Comment: You can *stop* the thread by selecting the official answer to your question. Just click on the checkbox near the answer to select it as the official. I'm afraid you will have to wait 48hrs before being able to select your own answer as the official one.

Comment: Just did it. Yupp it asked me to wait till tomorrow :P. Thanks!

Comment: Aah okay thanks for the clarification Steve. I don't want to create a tangent in this thread but does this also works for basic CGAL program??? If you know please help here: [Compile_Basic_CGAL_Program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8404968/compiling-a-basic-cgal-program-in-c-on-mac-os-x-10-7-2)

Answer (score 7):

Yay!!! This command worked:

```
g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

I just needed to add the path of `opencv.pc` file into the `.profile (or .bash_profile)` which is:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

Now I am trying to compile file which uses

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

instead of

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
```

I will reply soon if the same command works for this or not.
Thanks a lot guys for all the comments.

Comment: Okay the same command works perfectly fine for OpenCV code starting with `#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>`

Comment: Awesome, glad I've helped you. It's good pratice to upvote answers that you feel were useful to solve the problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You're close. `cvReleaseImage` is in opencv_core. I learned this by searching for `cvReleaseImage` at http://opencv.itseez.com. This worked for me:

```
g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world -I /usr/local/include/opencv -L /usr/local/lib  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core
```

It should work for you if you change `/usr` to `/opt`.

**Edit:**

Try making this change in your source code:

```
#include "opencv.hpp"
//#include <cv.h>
//#include <highgui.h>
```

I think the problem stems from the version mis-match between the tutorial code and the OpenCV 2.3 that you have installed. They changed the directory organization and the library names.

Comment: Also, that tutorial uses the old C-style OpenCV interface. You'd be much better off using the new C++-style interface. There are tutorials at http://opencv.itseez.com. Last time I looked a lot of them needed proofreading and editing but they're still helpful.

Comment: In the line `g++ example.cpp -o example -I /opt/local/include/opencv/ -L /opt/local/lib/ -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_legacy` you didn't include `-lopencv_core`. You don't need `-lopencv_legacy` or `-lopencv_calib3d`.

Comment: I just did the recommended changes but it won't change anything :(

Comment: If you don't show the results of the compilation attempt there's no way anyone can help you.

Comment: Oh Sorry I just posted the results below

Comment: But I didn't understand why this command `g++ hello-world.cpp -o hello-world -I /opt/local/include/opencv -L /opt/local/lib  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core` doesn't work.

Comment: It probably has something to do with what's installed on our systems. I had installed both OpenCV v1 and v2.3. Using pkg-config seems to mitigate installation issues.