# Compiling a basic CGAL program in C++ on Mac OS X 10.7.2

Tags: c++, macos, cgal

When I tried to compile Voronoi_Diagram_2 example I am getting this output:

```
singhg@~/Programming/examples/Voronoi_diagram_2 $ cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/opt/local/lib/cmake/
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:20 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    /opt/local//opt/local/lib/cmake/UseCGAL.cmake


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:22 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram


CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:26 (create_single_source_cgal_program):
  Unknown CMake command "create_single_source_cgal_program".


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Please help!

Comment: In CmakeLists.txt on Line 20, there is probably a wrong include path. Could you post that line? Well, it seems that there are more bad things going on… But let's see.

Comment: This looks suspicious: `/opt/local//opt/local/lib/...`

Comment: Here is the 20th line `include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )` And Here is the 22nd line:  `include( CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram )` And Here is the 26th line: ` create_single_source_cgal_program( "vd_2_point_location.cpp" )`

Comment: My major part of CmakeFile looks likes this: `if ( CGAL_FOUND )

  include( ${CGAL_USE_FILE} )

  include( CGAL_CreateSingleSourceCGALProgram )

  include_directories (BEFORE ../../include)

  create_single_source_cgal_program( "vd_2_point_location.cpp" )

else()
  
    message(STATUS "This program requires the CGAL library, and will not be compiled.")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Make CGAL3.9 work on Mac OS X 10.7.2 to run only CGAL examples(Demos will not run with this procedure)

- Download src code from the website

  - Extract it in your home directory
  - Open Terminal and go to the folder CGAL3.9
  - run cmake-gui . (don’t forget the dot after a space in this command)
  - Configure : upper window will look red
  - un-mark CGAL-QT3 and CGAL-QT4 in the camke-gui upper window
  - Configure again
  - make
  - make install
  - Done!

### To run demos:

- Install QT4 then open Cmake-gui in CGAL src code (of CGAL src code)

  - Mark CGAL_QT4 in the cmake-gui upper window
  - Configure again
  - make
  - make install
  - Done!

**Follow this link for further details and doubts:**
http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-a-basic-CGAL-program-in-C-on-Mac-OS-X-10-7-2-td4166413.html

**Compilation Command**
To Cmake CGAL Code:
cmake -DCGAL_DIR=/opt/local/lib/cmake

Comment: Or just look at the CGAL-manual in the section `3.1 Introduction`

Comment: can you explain how to do the same trick (at least the first part) directly from the command line? In particular, how do you tell cmake not to compile Qtx?